# How to properly add and remove a cursor component via entity's setAttribute?

Tags: aframe

Following the helpful change in approach suggested by ngokevin in my last question, I'm now trying to swap a cursor component between two entities (each a child of a separate camera). However, I'm seeing two behaviors I did not expect:

- When I call entityEl.removeAttribute('cursor'), it removes the cursor component, but leaves behind the implicitly added raycaster component. (Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oZgJOg)
- When I call entityEl.setAttribute('cursor'), I don't observe any additions to the entity in the inspector. (Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vxEvbG)

Where I can verify simply calling .removeAttribute('raycaster') after the first case resolves that problem, I'm not quite certain what prevents adding the cursor from working. Here's all the second demo's component does:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent( 'add-cursor-on-click', {
  init: function() {
    this.el.setAttribute('cursor'); 
    this.el.addEventListener( 'click', function() { console.log("Received click ev."); } );
  }
});

<a-entity id="onlyTheCursorAfterClick" add-cursor-on-click></a-entity>
```

As always, any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the remove lifecycle handlers for the cursor component were added recently so it only correctly behaves currently on master, see this pull request: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/2397

the cursor component also doesn't attach events right on its init. It waits for `render-target-loaded` (https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/2c0d9ed1efd93df841d207da5e7d2d69c67d8d3a/src/components/cursor.js#L50)

so in your component's init, if you wanted to remove the cursor component, in the component's init you'll need:

```
if (!canvas) {
      this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener('render-target-loaded', this.init.bind(this));
      return;
}
```

http://codepen.io/jhsu/pen/XMJQmE

Though, as you saw, you'll need to manually remove the raycaster still

```
this.el.removeAttribute('raycaster');
```

For adding the `cursor` component, you'll want to pass data for the component

```
this.el.setAttribute('cursor', {});
```

the reason is that there is a `undefined` [check when instantiating a component](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/2c0d9ed1efd93df841d207da5e7d2d69c67d8d3a/src/core/a-entity.js#L345).